# qgis link error because of libgeos.so

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, linker-errors, qgis, geos

When I try to build qgis-2.8.1 for arm on linux with cmake, I get the error below:

```
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libspatialiteprovider.so
[ 54%] Built target spatialiteprovider
Scanning dependencies of target crssync
[ 54%] Building CXX object src/crssync/CMakeFiles/crssync.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../output/bin/crssync
/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../geos/geos-3.3.9-imx53-shared/lib/libgeos_c.so: undefined reference to `std::auto_ptr<geos::geom::Envelope>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr_ref<geos::geom::Envelope>)'
/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../geos/geos-3.3.9-imx53-shared/lib/libgeos_c.so: undefined reference to `_ZNSt8auto_ptrIN4geos4geom8EnvelopeEEcvSt12auto_ptr_refIT_EIS2_EEv'
```

I tried to build qgis with this configuration:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"  
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/qgis-2.8.1-imx53-shared
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-DENABLE_TESTS=NO 
-DWITH_POSTGRESQL=NO 
-DWITH_GRASS=NO 
-DWITH_PY_COMPILE=NO 
-DWITH_BINDINGS=NO 
-DENABLE_QT5=NO 
-DWITH_QWTPOLAR=TRUE 
-DWITH_QSPATIALITE=FALSE 
-DWITH_PYSPATIALITE=FALSE 
-DPROJ_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../proj/proj-4.8.0-imx53-shared/include 
-DPROJ_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../proj/proj-4.8.0-imx53-shared/lib/libproj.so 
-DGEOS_CONFIG=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../geos/geos-3.3.9-imx53-shared/bin/geos-config 
-DGEOS_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../geos/geos-3.3.9-imx53-shared/include 
-DGEOS_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../geos/geos-3.3.9-imx53-shared/lib/libgeos_c.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../geos/geos-3.3.9-imx53-shared/lib/libgeos.so 
-DGDAL_CONFIG=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../gdal/gdal-1.11.2-imx53-shared/bin/gdal-config 
-DGDAL_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../gdal/gdal-1.11.2-imx53-shared/include 
-DGDAL_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../gdal/gdal-1.11.2-imx53-shared/lib/libgdal.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../libpng/libpng-1.6.3-imx53-shared/lib/libpng.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../libjpeg/jpeg-6b-imx53-shared/lib/libjpeg.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../libxml2/libxml2-2.7.8-imx53-shared/lib/libxml2.so 
-DGSL_CONFIG=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../gsl/gsl-1.9-imx53-shared/bin/gsl-config 
-DGSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../gsl/gsl-1.9-imx53-shared/include 
-DGSL_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../gsl/gsl-1.9-imx53-shared/lib/libgsl.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../gsl/gsl-1.9-imx53-shared/lib/libgslcblas.so 
-DSQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../sqlite3/sqlite-3080803-imx53-shared/include 
-DSQLITE3_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../sqlite3/sqlite-3080803-imx53-shared/lib/libsqlite3.so 
-DSPATIALITE_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../libspatialite/libspatialite-4.2.0-imx53-shared/include 
-DSPATIALITE_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../libspatialite/libspatialite-4.2.0-imx53-shared/lib/libspatialite.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../libspatialite/libspatialite-4.2.0-imx53-shared/lib/mod_spatialite.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../sqlite3/sqlite-3080803-imx53-shared/lib/libsqlite3.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../libiconv/libiconv-1.14-imx53-shared/lib/libcharset.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../libiconv/libiconv-1.14-imx53-shared/lib/libiconv.so 
-DSPATIALINDEX_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../spatialindex/spatialindex-1.7.0-imx53-shared/include 
-DSPATIALINDEX_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../spatialindex/spatialindex-1.7.0-imx53-shared/lib/libspatialindex.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../spatialindex/spatialindex-1.7.0-imx53-shared/lib/libspatialindex_c.so 
-DEXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../expat/expat-2.1.0-imx53-shared/include 
-DEXPAT_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../expat/expat-2.1.0-imx53-shared/lib/libexpat.so 
-DQWT_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../qwt/qwt-6.1.1-emb_imx53-shared/include 
-DQWT_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../qwt/qwt-6.1.1-emb_imx53-shared/lib/libqwt.so;/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../qwt/qwt-6.1.1-emb_imx53-shared/lib/libqwtmathml.so 
-DQWTPOLAR_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../qwtpolar/qwtpolar-1.1.1-imx53-shared/include 
-DQWTPOLAR_LIBRARY=/home/lib/trunk/qgis/../qwtpolar/qwtpolar-1.1.1-imx53-shared/lib/libqwtpolar.so 
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=/home/toolchain/imx53 -DCMAKE_AR=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-ar 
-DCMAKE_RANLIB=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-ranlib 
-DCMAKE_NM=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-nm 
-DCMAKE_OBJCOPY=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-objcopy 
-DCMAKE_OBJDUMP=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-objdump 
-DCMAKE_STRIP=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-strip 
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

Also, I built geos-3.3.9 with this configuration:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"  
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/lib/trunk/geos/geos-3.3.9-imx53-shared 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-DGEOS_ENABLE_TESTS=OFF 
-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF 
-DHAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64=OFF 
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=/home/toolchain/imx53 
-DCMAKE_AR=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-ar 
-DCMAKE_RANLIB=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-ranlib 
-DCMAKE_NM=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-nm 
-DCMAKE_OBJCOPY=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-objcopy 
-DCMAKE_OBJDUMP=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-objdump 
-DCMAKE_STRIP=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-strip 
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/toolchain/imx53/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

When I take a look at the build error of qgis, I think that this problem is caused by some configuration error of geos at built. But I do not find anything. Also I tried to assign the geos path to rpath for qgis, nothing changed.

I do not know why I get this error. If somebody has an idea, please guide me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled C++11?

Comment: No. I didn't enable C++11. Why do I need to enable C++? Could you explain it?

Comment: Most C++ compilers use by default the C++ standard from 1998 or 2003. There is a new standard C++11 from 2011. Enable it by passing `-std=c++11` or for older compiler `-std=c++0x`. You have to add it to the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

Comment: I could not find anything stating that you should enable c++11 for qgis or geos.

Comment: Just try it. Here some more information about GEOS, C++11 and auto_ptr (from 2011!): http://lwg.github.io/issues/lwg-closed.html#2068

Comment: I tried to build geos with C++11. But build failed because of isnan being ambigous. Also, I built geos, qgis and all of their dependencies on my local computer they are built with no problem. It seems that there is something else that causes link problem. But I cannot find it.

Comment: Maybe you try the latest GEOS version 3.4.2 and not 3.3.9.

Comment: I tried GEOS version 3.4.2. I get the same error. Nothing changed.